# Finding the difference in two MySQL tables that should be identical

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL databases: one for testing, and one for production. They are on different servers. These tables should be identical, however one table has one more row than the other. How would I find this row?

Comment: The two databases are on different machines.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

1. Export second server table in a SQL file (using MySqlDump)
2. Edit file changing table name
3. Import SQL file into first server

Then run

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This won't actually work for certain. Just because one table has one more row than the other doesn't mean it has all the rows plus one.  It's possible that we could have the following: the first table has rows ABCDEF, and the second has ACDEFGH. If there is a difference in the row count, you should also suspect a difference in row contents, so some rows with the same IDs might have different data in other columns. You need to use a tool like pt-table-sync to get good results.

Answer (score 3):

One way is export each table to an sql file and use a diff program to find the differences.

Pretty Diff (web) - http://prettydiff.com/

WinMerge (win) - http://winmerge.org/

FileMerge (OS X) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge

Comment: Updated to winmerge.. windows was from memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
pt-table-sync --print h=server1,D=dbname,t=tablename h=server2
```

See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than any type of export-and-compare suggested by other posters.

Answer (score 0):

we use http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 0):

A trick I have done sometimes (you need access to both tables):

1. Open Access or similar
2. Link table from server A
3. Link table from server B
4. Calculate difference in Access

Obviously, you have to be careful if the tables are large.